# Changing columns that are string in Spark GraphFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, graphframes

I'm using GraphFrame in spark 2.0 and scala.

I need to remove double quote from columns that are in string type (out of many columns). 
I'm trying to do so using UDF as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val removeDoubleQuotes = udf( (x:Any) =>
    x match{
      case s:String => s.replace("\"","")
      case other => other
    }
  )
```

And I get the following error since type Any is not supported in GraphFrame.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not
>   supported

What is a workaround for that?

Comment: Do your columns have mixed types? Why not just write it only for strings and apply it only to the string columns?

Comment: @JoeK Because I have many columns and try to find a way rather than manually find string columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a column with type `Any` and you can't return different datatype from `udf`. You need to have a single datatype return from `udf`.

If your column is String then you can create `udf` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val removeDoubleQuotes = udf( (x:String) => s.replace("\"",""))
```